# Mongoose: cannot access populated value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I can see the populated value in the console but when trying to access it I'm getting `undefined`:

```js
const AccountProfile = new Schema({
  owner: { type: String },
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  countryId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Country" }
});

const Country = new Schema({
    name: String
});

AccountProfile.statics.getProfile = function (username, cb) {
    this.model("AccountProfile").findOne({owner: username})
    .populate("countryId")
    .exec(function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        console.log(profile.countryId);
        return cb(null, profile);
    });
};
```

The output has the following format: `{ _id: 57a9d5cda3c91dda14eb50f0, Name: 'UK' }`

Printing `profile.countryId._id` looks fine, but `profile.countryId.Name` is `undefined`!

Any clue? Using mongoose version 4.6.6

Comment: Check if there are any spaces in the key

Comment: Can you please show the Country schema ?

Comment: @chridam It doesn't seem to be the problem. The output of `JSON.stringify(profile.countryId)` is `{"_id":"57a9d5cda3c91dda14eb50f0","Name":"UK"}`

Comment: @RizwanJamal Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Schema you have defined the field "name" not "Name" 
Try with getting `profile.countryId.name`

Comment: but how you getting "Name" in console........ if its not defined in `Country` Schema

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that in the actual mongo document the field was called `Name` while in my code `name` (I created the mongoose schema after importing existing data to mongo that I wanted to access using code). So I had to rename my field in the mongoose schema to `Name` to be consistent with what was in mongo. That explains why `Name` was printed in the console